# Google Translate in VB .Net returning ??? for Arabic Language

Tags: vb.net, google-translate

I am working on a small function that translates string to different languages. Actually it's working fine for all languages except Arabic, it's returning question marks ????. Any hint? You can view the code below

Thanks in advance

```
 Dim translateThis = "hello"
 Dim languagePair = "en|ar"
 Dim url3 = String.Format("http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&text={0}&langpair={1}", translateThis, languagePair)
 Dim result as string

 Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
 client.Encoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8

 result = client.DownloadString(url3)
 result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("id=result_box") + 151, 500)
 result = result.Substring(0, result.IndexOf("</span>"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use for Arabic Windows Encoding(1256) :

```
client.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256)
```

Comment: Glad to help you! Thank you too :)